# What is exact math behind css3 matrix3d fourth column?

Tags: css, math, matrix

I'm trying to figure out final coordinates based on data from matrix3d and I understand everything except fourth column, how does it affect final results? It looks like it is kind of perspective, but I couldn't recreate its math. It seems like different offsets in last row also affects in changing final shape when last column applied.

So if we have:

```
matrix3d(m00, m01, m02, m03,
         m10, m11, m12, m13,
         m20, m21, m22, m23,
         m30, m31, m32, m33)
```

where:

```
m30: X offset;
m31: Y offset;
m32: Z offset;
```

Offset math is simple: after multiplying, these values are added to corresponding values in vector (if m03, m13, m23, m33 is zero), but what I'm looking for is a equastions which stands behind: m03, m13, m23, m33. For Chrome at least (it might be that other browsers do other math)

Comment: Isn't that described on [css-transform functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function). If it is not describe which part you find unclear.

Comment: They call it there "translation" and as example give a picture with kind of offset which already confuses me because this is what last row is suposed to do (at least in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/paulsidebottom/jbfSj/). And still there is no single equastion saying what is happening with vector treated with matrix.

Comment: And I don't mean just multiplying because it is clearly not only that.

Comment: And BTW. I did research, I've spend on it whole day, and was trying to solve this problem, so if the answer would be obvious I wouldn't ask. Believe me! :-)

Comment: You should really edit your findings in your question. Visitors of your question don't want to spend also a day on the research you've already done...

Comment: -1 from me rene, you should read carefully question before giving me -1 :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this 4x4 matrix is used to transform 3D vectors, it is a homogeneous matrix. Homogeneous space adds another dimension to the base space, which is referred to as the w-component. So before a vector (representing a point) is transformed with the matrix, a w-component of 1 is added to it, making it a 4D vector. Then the multiplication is performed:

```
                           / m00 m01 m02 m03 \
(x' y' z' w') = (x y z 1)  | m10 m11 m12 m13 |
                           | m20 m21 m22 m23 |
                           \ m30 m31 m32 m33 /
```

The resulting homogeneous vector is then converted back to a 3D vector through the w-clip (dividing by w)

```
(x'' y'' z'') = 1/w' * (x' y' z')
```

So if you alter the last column of the matrix, you affect `w'`. Usually, this is used for perspective transforms and the last row becomes something like `(0 0 1 0)`. This means that the resulting `w` component is directly its input vertex' z-component. This basically means that the output vertex is smaller the farther away it is from the origin (only considering the z-direction).